# Confused about Enderton's mathematical logic notation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am currently reading Enderton's math logic text. I am on section 1.7 where he is proving the compactness theorem. I came across this weird notation that I have never seen before; then I referred to his chapter 0.

He states: A useful operation is that of adjoining one extra object to a set. For a set $A$, let $A$; $t$ be the set whose members are (i) the members of $A$, plus (ii) the (possibly new) member $t$. Here $t$ may or may not already belong to $A$, and we have

$A; t = A \cup \{t\}$

He uses this notation to prove the compactness theorem. So does this mean that we are redefining $t$ like how they do it in programming languages?

For example, $t = 2$ and $A = \{1,3\}$. Then, $A; t = A \cup \{t\}$ redefines $t = \{1,2,3\}$. Sorry if this a stupid question, but I don't really get it.

Answer (score 4):

I’m not sure I see any redefining going on here. In the example you gave,

$A$ stands for $\{1,3\}$,

$t$ stands for $2$, and

$A;t$ stands for $\{1,2,3\}$.

Maybe you can clarify your confusion a bit more.

Comment: I believe the confusion comes from programming language where `;` is used to separate statements, so OP read $A;t=A\cup\{t\}$ as the two "statements" $A$ and $t=A\cup \{t\}$ (which in some programming languages would redefine $t$ using its old value), vs reading it as a single equation $(A;t)=A\cup\{t\}$ (parentheses added for emphasis)

Comment: Using `=` for assignment wasn't the best choice ever made when coming up with a programming language!

Answer (score 2):

In reading a mathematical definition, you need to be careful about bringing in ideas from other places.  In particular, this is *not* a text on programming, and one should not assume that notation from any particular programming language is related to the notation being defined in the text.

When an author writes something like "Let ___ be...," they are introducing a new symbol, and then telling you exactly what that symbol means.  In this case,

> For a set $A$, let $A\mathbin{;}t$ be the set whose members are (i) the members of $A$, plus (ii) the (possibly new) member $t$.

Here, the new symbol "$A\mathop{;} t$" is being introduced.  You should, for the moment, regard this as *one* symbol.  The author then explains what this new symbol means:  it is a set whose elements are all the elements of $A$, plus the possibly new element $t$.  That is, the set which is denoted by the single symbol "$A\mathop{;} t$" is the union of $A$ and $\{t\}$, i.e.
$$ A\mathop{;} t = A \cup \{t\}. $$
Again, the *entire symbol* to the left of the equals is being defined.  Hence
$$ \{1,3\} \mathop{;} 2 = \{1,2,3\}. $$

In this case, it might also be helpful to regard the symbol "$;$" as a binary operator or function, similar to "$+$", "$\cap$", or "$\times$".  The symbol "$;$" sits between a set (on the left) and an object (on the right), and "combines" them in some way.  Specifically, it includes the object into the set.

Comment: Maybe a tweak is needed? Python uses `append` to mutate lists so "appends the object to the set" might cause similar confusion to `=` interpreted as assignment. Sorry for nitpicking, it just struck me as I read your answer.

Comment: @DanielMGessel Honestly, I am not sure that there is a good way to completely avoid some bit of language which is going to be overloaded to *somebody*, but I have made a small change.